# modified condition /Decision coverage analysis tool in java

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, mc-dc

Are there any opensource tools for modified condition /Decision coverage analysis in java.

I have looked at coberta and it seems it only provides conditional coverage.

I am interested in performing the analyis described  here

http://sunnyday.mit.edu/papers/dupuy.pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage

> To satisfy the MC/DC coverage criterion, during testing all of the
>   below must be true at least once[1]:
>
> ```
> * Each decision tries every possible outcome
> * Each condition in a decision takes on every possible outcome
> * Each entry and exit point is invoked
> * Each condition in a decision is shown to independently affect the outcome of the decision
> ```

Answer (score 4):

## MC/DC - Multiple Condition/Decision coverage

> Every point of entry and exit in the program has been invoked at least once, every condition in a decision in the program has taken on all possible outcomes at least once, and each condition has been shown to affect that decision outcome independently. A condition is shown to affect a decision's outcome independently by varying just that condition while holding fixed all other possible conditions.
>   [Wikipedia MC/DC - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage]

## CodeCover

http://codecover.org/features/coverage.html

CodeCover states to also check for MC/DC, they call it Term Coverage in the sense of the Ludewig term. I tried to find additional information about Ludewig terms but I couldn't find any useful information about it.

### Term coverage (CodeCover)

Term coverage checks for boolean short circuit semantics, like decisions that involve side effects which are not always evaluated:

```
if (expressionA && myfunc(b)) {
    do_something();
}
```

[Wikipedia Short-circuit evaluation - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation]

If expressionA evaluates to false, myfunc(b) will not be executed. This is a common technique to write faster code, but is risky because myfunc(b) could do some changes to the environment, which can be easily overseen by developers and thus creating insecure code.

From my understanding Term coverage verifies that expressionA evaluates to both true and false, so that myfunc(b) gets at least executed once.

## Testwell CTC++

http://www.verifysoft.com/en_ctcpp.html

- Proprietary software with licenses starting from 4100 € to 8800 €
- Seems to support C, C++, Java, C#
- Supports all compilers
- Compliance with DO 178-C / ED-12C (Aerospace), EN 50128 (Railway), IEC 61508 (electronic safety-related systems), IEC 62304 (Medical), ISO 26262 (Automotive), IEC 60880 (Nuclear Power) and other quality standards.

PS: I had not enough reputations to post more than two links, therefor I made them unparseable. But they are still important in the means of a citation reference.